# What are the components of the set of irrational numbers?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

$X=\Bbb R$\  $ \Bbb Q $, standard topology

What are the components of X?

Is it for all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, for all $a <c<b$, (a, b)  are the components?

or just for all $z \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \cup \{z\} $?

Comment: Certainly not. Components are disjoint, assuming you mean connected components.

Comment: @Travis: The connected components of a set needn't be open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x$ and $y$ be distinct irrational numbers. There is a rational number $q$ between $x$ and $y$. The sets $(\leftarrow,q)\setminus\Bbb Q$ and $(q,\to)\setminus\Bbb Q$ are disjoint clopen subsets of $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, and their union is $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$. One of them contains $x$, and the other contains $y$; can $x$ and $y$ be in the same connected component of $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$?